# Rails 4: how to access an attribute of an ActiveRecord_Relation-Object?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

i have a country model and a travel note model.
A country has many travel notes and a travel note belongs to one country.

in Rails console:

```
 TravelNote.published.country(248)
```

`[#<TravelNote id: 172, country_id: 248, status: 1, advice_against: 0, published_at: "2012-10-04 07:57:00", created_at: "2014-09-23 09:09:20", updated_at: "2014-09-23 09:09:20">]`

```
TravelNote.published.country(248).published_at
NameError: undefined local variable or method `published_at' for #<Class:0x00000005a84968>
```

How can i get the published_at attribute of this object?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
TravelNote.published.country(248)
```

returns an array of records, so you have to grab the first item of the array:

```
TravelNote.published.country(248).first.published_at
```